# Showing that for continuous logarithms $g_1, g_2$ of a function on a connected set, the difference $g_1 −g_2$ is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

> If $S$ is connected, $\ f$ is continuous and has continuous logarithms $g_1$ and $g_2$ on $S$, and continuous arguments $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, then $g_1 −g_2$ and $\theta_1-\theta_2$ are constant on $S$

If $f$ has continuous logarithms $g_1,g_2$:

$f(s)=e^{g_1(s)}=e^{g_2(s)}\implies g_1(s)-g_2(s)=2\pi ik(s)\ $, for some $k(s)\in\mathbb Z$

now if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous, so is $k$, hence it must be a constant , but where did we use the fact that, $S$ is connected, do you have an counterexample such that the result is false for a not connected set ?

Comment: How did you get "now if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are continuous, so is $k$, hence it must be a constant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct conclusion is that
$$g_1(s) - g_2(s) = 2 \pi i k(s)$$
for some continuous function $k: S \mapsto \Bbb Z$, rather than for some constant we denote $k(s)$. Now, since $k$ is continuous and $\Bbb Z$ is discrete, $k$ is constant on each connected component. In particular, if $S$ is connected, it only has one component as $k$ is a bona fide constant as desired.

This also tells you how to construct a counterexample: Pick a set $S$ with two connected components, say, $S_1, S_2$, and a function $f: S \to \Bbb C$ that admits a continuous logarithm $g$. Then, by construction for any $C \in 2 \pi i \Bbb Z - \{ 0 \}$, the function
$$\widetilde{g}(s) :=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
g(s), & s \in S_1 \\
g(s) + C, & s \in S_2
\end{array}
\right.$$
is also a continuous logarithm of $g$ but $\widetilde{g} - g$ is not constant: It is $0$ on $S_1$ and $C \neq 0$ on $S_2$.

Comment: how is then $\tilde{g}$ continuous, do we consider $S_1$ and $S_2$ separately, in the real case it would not be continuous, right ?

Comment: @Elaqqad Yes, thank you, I updated the answer.

Comment: @ketum Yes, it's basically that we can treat $S_1$ and $S_2$ from the p.o.v. of continuity, because they are different components (note that this is more or less the definition of component). There is no (interesting) real analogue of this statement, as a (positive) real function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R_+$ only has one logarithm, namely, $\log f$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $s\to k(s)$ must take integer values only so if it's continous than it's constant which gives you $g_1-g_2=2i\pi k$ for some constant $k$.

Where we used here $S$ connected? we used in order to deduce the implication :
$k(s)$ continuous and $k(s)\in \Bbb N$ implies that $k(s)$ is constant, but how?
the genralisation of the intermediate value theorem says that if $S$ is connected than $k(S)$ is connected but the only connected subsets of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb C$ are those of the form $\{k\}$